# How to covert NSMutableOrderedSet to generic array?

Tags: ios, generics, swift, nsorderedset

I have this for loop, `p` is a `NSManagedObject`, `fathers` is a `to-many` relationship, so I need to cast `NSMutableOrderedSet` to `[Family]` but it does not work, why?

```
for f in p.fathers as [Family] {
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can obtain an array representation of the set via the `array` property - then you can downcast it to the proper type and assign to a variable:

```
let families = p.fathers.array as [Family]
```

but of course you can also use it directly in the loop:

```
for f in p.fathers.array as [Family] {
    ....
}
```

**Update**

A forced downcast is now required using the `!` operator, so the code above should be:

```
let families = p.fathers.array as! [Family]
```

Comment: While `.array` is still there, I am not able to cast to an array of another type: `Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to type '[T]' in coercion`

Comment: You have to do a forced conversion, i.e. `as! [Family]`

Answer (score 5):

The simple solution by [Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148357/antonio) should be used in this case. I'd just like to discuss this a bit more. If we try to enumerate an instance of `'NSMutableOrderedSet'` in a `'for'` loop, the compiler will complain:

> error: type 'NSMutableOrderedSet' does not conform to protocol
>   'SequenceType'

When we write

```
for element in sequence {
    // do something with element
}
```

the compiler rewrites it into something like this:

```
var generator = sequence.generate()

while let element = generator.next() {
    // do something with element
}
```

`'NS(Mutable)OrderedSet'` doesn't have `'generate()'` method i.e. it doesn't conform to the `'SequenceType'` protocol. We can change that. First we need a generator:

```
public struct OrderedSetGenerator : GeneratorType {

    private let orderedSet: NSMutableOrderedSet

    public init(orderedSet: NSOrderedSet) {
        self.orderedSet = NSMutableOrderedSet(orderedSet: orderedSet)
    }

    mutating public func next() -> AnyObject? {
        if orderedSet.count > 0 {
            let first: AnyObject = orderedSet.objectAtIndex(0)
            orderedSet.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
            return first
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can use that generator to make `'NSOrderedSet'` conform to `'SequenceType'`:

```
extension NSOrderedSet : SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> OrderedSetGenerator {
        return OrderedSetGenerator(orderedSet: self)
    }
}
```

`'NS(Mutable)OrderedSet'` can now be used in a `'for'` loop:

```
let sequence = NSMutableOrderedSet(array: [2, 4, 6])

for element in sequence {
    println(element) // 2 4 6
}
```

We could further implement `'CollectionType'` and `'MutableCollectionType'` (the latter for `'NSMutableOrderedSet'` only) to make `'NS(Mutable)OrderedSet'` behave like Swift's standard library collections.

Not sure if the above code follows the best practises as I'm still trying to wrap my head around details of all these protocols.